# Sending email through proxy using gmail smtp JAVA

Tags: java, proxy, smtp

I'm trying to send a email in Java, I'm using a server proxy.

I've specified the proxy settings like that but doesn't works.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("http.proxyHost", "192.168.20.2");  
props.put("http.proxyPort", "321");  
props.put("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

try {
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("asdf@gmail.com"));  
    message.setSubject("SUBJECT");
    message.setText("BODY");
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", sender,pass); //exception here!!!
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
}
catch (MessagingException me) {
    me.printStackTrace();   
}
```

And I'm getting this exception because the code doesn't connect to internet.

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
```

Somebody knows why the program isn't taking the specified proxy?

Comment: My guess is that you won't be able to use a proxy without SSL-enabling it, as I've a feeling that GMail won't allow non-SSL transport

Comment: @g00se I've `props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");` and doesn't works. :/

Comment: Ah you misunderstand – I don't mean TLS-enabling your app. I mean TLS-enabling your proxy (not tirvial)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using JavaMail?

If that's the case, you probably are using the wrong properties, there are different ways to configure it depending on your proxy's authentication and JavaMail version you're using: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ.html#proxy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).